# How to estimate the disk space for 1 million rows if I have a table of fewer rows in InnoDB MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I want to estimate the disk space for 1 million rows.

[image]

Currently, I have 8527959 rows, Data Length of 744 MB and Index Length 989.4 MB.

Please let me know if my calculations are correct.

### Total Data Length for 1 million rows

Data of 744MB consists of 46500 pages of 16KB blocks (InnoDB page size)

If 46500 pages consist of 8527959 rows, 1 page consists an average of 183 rows.

So, 1 million rows need (1,000,000/183) pages= 5465 pages of 16KB

So, 1 million rows of data need 87.4MB.

### Total Index Length for 1 million rows

Indexes of of 989.4MB consists of 61837 pages of 16KB blocks (InnoDB page size)

If 61837 pages consist of 8527959 rows, 1 page consists an average of 138 rows.

So, 1 million rows need (1,000,000/138) pages= 7247 pages of 16KB

So, 1 million rows of data need 115.9MB.

### Total disk space (approximate) for 1 million rows

Total data length+Total Index Length = 87.4MB + 115.9 MB = 203.3 MB

Is this correct?

Comment: I think I can answer this with a valuable response for others, too, different than those others.

Comment: Sizes are roughly proportional. Several hiccups can occur: Allocation starts with 16KB blocks (a 1-row table will take 16KB for data), then moves to 8MB "extents" (or something like that). But when you are talking about millions of rows, the hiccups are more "random".

Answer (score 4):

Your basic assumptions are correct, it is easy to see that the allocation per row is just under 100 bytes per row, and a bit more for the indexes, giving you a 200 * 1M = 200M of total size.

However, several important things have to be taken into account:

- The tables must have identical structure and equivalent content- e.g. the same exact table with similar sized variable content.
- With `SHOW TABLE STATUS` you are getting an estimation of size (rows, total size) based on sampling- it may not be accurate, specially if large changes happened to the table and automatic sampling didn't kick-off yet. You can force statistics gathering with `ANALYZE TABLE` command, but it can never guarantee you 100% accuracy
- Everything is related to the *logical size*, not to *physical size*, or size on disk. If you were to delete 7/8ths of that table, the disk used on disk wouldn't shrink in the case of InnoDB, because disk defragmentation wouldn't happen- space is freed for other rows to be inserted, but it wouldn't be released to the filesystem. To reduce the on-disk size, you would need to recreate the table with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, a more time consuming and blocking operations.
- If disk space is a concern, consider using compression